# Property 'Op' does not exist on type 'typeof Sequelize'

Tags: typescript, tsc, sequelize-typescript

I'm getting this error on build using tsc

import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';

Property 'Op' does not exist on type 'typeof Sequelize'.

52               [Sequelize.Op.not]: false
                            ~~

my package json

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-statsd": "^0.3.0",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.0",
    "hashids": "^1.2.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
    "mysql2": "^1.5.1",
    "nyc": "^13.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.7",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^1.1.0",
    "strong-error-handler": "^2.3.0",
    "supertest": "^3.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.0.39",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.41",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.4",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.4.1",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
```

can someone help?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If my answer below doesn't cover it, then you need to provide more info, otherwise this question will be closed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There is no symbol Op in the entire 'sequelize-typescript' source. This is a typo. Perhaps you meant SequelizeOptions? In the future, look at the source (it's in node_modules). Or look again at the docs.

Answer (score 8):

Try using this import

```
import {Op} from "sequelize";

...

{[Op.eq]: false}
```